Play store submission: Update your target API level by August 31, 2023 to release updates to your app
We received a notification from the Google Play Store on August 18th, 2023, about updating our target API level by August 31, 2023. We missed this deadline but are working on updating the app, planning to release it by August 2024.
Our last release was in July 2023, and we're revamping the app from Ionic to Flutter to meet the latest Android API requirements. Will our app be removed from the Play Store during this period? What steps should we take to keep the existing bundle ID and maintain our customer base if we can't update in time?
Thanks in advance.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Hi, im facing the same issue, but the deadline for me i 1. Nov. How did things work out for you, did you get blocked, or could you update it after the deadline?

It could be removed, but from my experience this is unlikely. but your app is not appearing on devices with newer Android versions, which is hurting your numbers.
Removal of the app is reversible, just update the app and wait for a review (could take up to 7 days) so your app bundle ID is safe if the app got removed.
I recommend releasing an open beta build as soon as possible even if it is not complete, you can set the rollout to 0.00001% to ensure no one will install it, but this way you may walk around this policy for now.
I hope this helped, and good luck.
